# Issues setting up a back ground image and with UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview

On my iPhone app, I simply want to set a particular background image, which depends on whether it's an iPhone 5 or not.

So, I tried two approaches:
A) Using

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backGroundimage];
```

B) Creating an UIImageView and setting up the image there. Code:

```
UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:screenBounds];
[backgroundImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:backGroundImage]];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImageView];
```

But I am having issues with both of them:

Issues with Step A:
When I set the image through that way, I have to deal with the image scaling issues for different sizes of the screen. I use the following code to do the scalling:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenBounds.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:backGroundImage] drawInRect:screenBounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

Another issue from Step A is that the image appears quite blurry. It doesn't have the same sharpness to it.

Issues with Step B:
With this, the image looks really crisp and sharp - just the way it should look.

But when I switch to another view using the following code, strangely enough the UIImageView backgroundImageView still appears on the second one.  The code I use to switch views is:

```
[self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I even tried `[backgroundImageView removeFromSuperview]`, but that doesn't solve anything either.

So what am I doing wrong? And how can I set up a picture as my background which is dependent on the size of the iphone?

Comment: self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backGroundimage];

What is backGroundimage in this?

Comment: backGroundImage is not the problem here. It refers to the name of the image like, @"background.png" or @"backgroundiPhone5.png", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Plan B is a good plan.  Presenting another view controller should and will definitely hide your image view.  If it isn't happening, then it's a problem with the creation of secondViewController, unrelated to the background image on the presenting VC.

Before presenting secondViewController, log it:

```
NSLog(@"presenting %@", secondViewController);
```

I'll bet a dollar that it's nil.  If I'm right, let's have a look at how you initialize secondViewController.  That's the problem, unrelated to the background image view.

Comment: I logged the secondViewController and unfortunately it isn't nil. Here's the code that I use to initialize my second controller: SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; I remember having this same exact issue with another project, to the point that I just got rid of the UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally fixed this issue, although the cause of this issue is still puzzling to me.

To fix this, I had to create an IBOutlet property for UIImageView and hook it up on the XIB file.

The reason I was programmatically creating the UIImageView is because the size of the UIImageView depends on what size iPhone they are using. But for the IBOutlet (let's call it as UIImageViewOutlet, I simply used [self.UIImageViewOutlet setFrame:] to get the size and location that I wanted.

I also discovered that one of the buttons that I was programmatically creating, was still visible in the secondViewController. I ended up creating an Outlet on the XIB file for that one as well and used setFrame on it to position it properly.

If anyone who knows the reason of this problem, I will be very grateful.

Comment: If you dont mind provide your code for solving your issue . Because i'm not getting any issue in my sample project.